# typecasting in C

Tags: c, casting

In my code I get this error :

```
expected ‘const void *’ but argument is of type ‘struct in_addr’
```

I am using `memcmp` can i type cast `struct in_addr` to `const void*` as `const void * (struct in_addr )`

Comment: Ed S@  memcmp(const void* &((*temp).pktFltr.ip.ip_src), const void * &(ptr_fltr->pktFltr.ip.ip_src),32);  i have tyecast it i get a error : error: expected expression before ‘const’
 error: too few arguments to function ‘memcmp’

Answer (score 7):

You need to cast the *address* of your object, not the object itself:

```
(const void *)&my_obj
```

But in fact, such casts are implict, so you can just use:

```
&my_obj
```

Comment: Oli Charlesworth @   memcmp(const void* &((*temp).pktFltr.ip.ip_src), const void * &(ptr_fltr->pktFltr.ip.ip_src),32);  i have tyecast it i get a error : error: expected expression before ‘const’
 error: too few arguments to function ‘memcmp’

Comment: @asir, casts need the parenthesis around them `(const void*)`

Comment: @asir: also please observe the simple syntax at SO. The `@` comes before a persons name. Code should be put into backticks such that it stands out `like that` to be easier to capture.